# PHP Upload for certain file type, "invalid filetype"?

Tags: php, file-upload

So I'm trying to add an upload function to a contact page that will only allow certain file types.  The files should be stored in the root in an "upload" folder.  However, the files are not being uploaded and I'm getting an "invalid file" error (as programmed) on a PDF and a docx file but can't figure out why.  Can anyone offer any insight?

```
<?php

    if($_POST) {

      if($_POST["token"]==true){
        $allowedExts = array("pdf","docx", "doc");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/docx")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/doc"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 6144) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
              {
              echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
              }
            else
              {
              move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . rand().$extension);
              echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . "rand().$extension)";
              }
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
?>
```

Comment: Should `docx` be in your allowed extensions array? It is currently not there. Have you tried to debug this to determine where you are getting values you do not expect?

Comment: And `echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]` to make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: As it is now, those braces do not match. It's obviously not the source of error, but it bugs me, how does it even compile?

Comment: good catch, i've adjusted

Answer (score 0):

The filetype for a docx file is not `application/docx` but `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`, though you may also see it as `application/zip`; the mime type for a doc file is `application/msword`
, not `application/doc`

Comment: On top of that, `docx` is not even in the `$allowedExts` array.

Comment: @kba - true as well; and a host of image formats are in the allowed extensions list, but no tests for their type